# RabbitMQ Java Consumer( NOT spring)

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, consumer

I am having a problem keeping my consumer connected to the queue. I'm verifying the connection via the rmq web interface.Below you can find my code I use to connect my consumer.

Here is where I am getting confused, if the queue is empty when I connect- everything works fine. It stays connected until I interrupt it.

However, if I connect to the queue while there is something there, it consumes those items and then it stops consuming altogether.

```
 Callable<Void> callable2 = new Callable<Void>()
       {
          @Override
          public Void call() throws Exception
          {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Reading");
            Channel c = createChannel();
              readQueue(propertiesMap.get("close_rabbitmq_response"),c);
              return null;
          }

public static ConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new ConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(propertiesMap.get("close_rabbitmq_url"));
    connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(propertiesMap.get("close_rabbitmq_vh"));
    connectionFactory.setUsername(propertiesMap.get("close_rabbitmq_username"));
    connectionFactory.setPassword(propertiesMap.get("close_rabbitmq_password"));
    return connectionFactory;
}
public static Channel createChannel() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    ConnectionFactory cf = createConnectionFactory();
    com.rabbitmq.client.Connection connection =  cf.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    return channel;
}


public static void readQueue(String queueName,Channel c) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
        String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        byte[] mapData = message.getBytes();
        Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        myMap = objectMapper.readValue(mapData, HashMap.class);
        System.out.println("Recived Payload "+myMap.get("batchId"));
        try {
            updateResponse.setLong(1,Long.parseLong(myMap.get("batchId")));
            updateResponse.setString(2, "C");
            updateResponse.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    c.basicConsume(queueName, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });

}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code gives any hint on what could be the problem.

Comment: @LutzHorn I figured as much. Included it anyways, was hoping some rabbitmq built in logic I was missing...